# Add Coveo rendering statically

Tags: coveo

I'm trying to add a Coveo search box view to my page statically, using `@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("ID OF RENDERING")`. I created my own copy of the rendering, and also my own copy of the rendering parameters so I could set the ID and search page in the standard values. The resources appear if I add those statically, but the search box view doesn't. The same view does appear if I add it via placeholder.

Ideally, I add my header/footer statically so users can't remove them. Is there something I'm missing? It seems like this should be a no-brainer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to add a datasource for the rendering, with the data using the Coveo Search Box Parameters template. So using the syntax `@Html.Sitecore().Rendering("RENDERING ID", new { DataSource = "DATASOURCE ID" })` will do it.